# How to rewrite 'column => self[column]' field generic hash rocket to ruby 1.9 hash format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can the below (specifically `User.exists?(column => self[column])`) be re-written in Ruby's 1.9 hash syntax?

```
 def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't. The new hash syntax is simpler syntax because it assumes the keys are symbols.

Building hashes with symbol keys have become very common. For instance, in rails:

```
has_many :foos, :class_name => "Bar", :foreign_key => "baz", :auto_save => true
```

There is some syntactic sugar to simplify this code:

```
has_many :foos, class_name: "Bar", foreign_key: "baz", auto_save: true
```

But if your keys are anything other than bare symbols, the old syntax still applies. In your case, the keys are coming from a variable.

Comment: Thank you for confirming